# How can I get the logo/icon of an app with path

Tags: python

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe'
os.startfile(path)
```

What I want, in this situation for example we have Spotify, is to save the logo somewhere based on its path.
I want to use it for a tkinter app I have built.

Maybe something in the idea of:

```
my_image = get_image_from_path(file=r'C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe')
```

Comment: The icons are stored in the executable as a resource.  You will have to use the Win32 resource APIs to fetch them from inside the exe.

Comment: I have been looking at the documentation but I still cant get my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This draws an icon from a given executable into a bitmap, and saves the bitmap.

My web searching to answer this question brought up a thread on the pywin32 mailing list from 2009.  I don't remember writing it, but this is the code from my reply:

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx("c:/windows/system32/shell32.dll",0)
win32gui.DestroyIcon(large[0])

hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, ico_x, ico_y )
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )
hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), small[0] )
hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, "save.bmp" )
```

Comment: Is there a way to not save the image in the same directory as the .py file but in another one?

Comment: Like every API that takes a file name, all you have to do is provide the path.

Comment: Yeah, stupid question found it ... Thanks a lot. Just changed `"save.bmp"` to  `path/save.bmp`

Comment: Can you take a look of the `ico_y` variable I think it is never being used, I dont know if it matters

Comment: The parameters to `CreateCompatibleBitmap` should probably be `ico_x, ico_y`, but since all Windows icon formats are square, it hardly matters.